Unable to resolve "../Utilities/Platform" from "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactPrivate\ReactNativePrivateInterface.js"
This error is not for using react-native-maps as some solutions are available.
I am using Expo and React native to develop a simple application but getting this error.
Thanks for the help anyone can offer here !
My package.json is
 "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-clipboard": "~6.0.3",
    "expo-crypto": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.10",
    "expo-image": "~1.12.15",
    "expo-localization": "~15.0.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "firebase": "^10.13.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },


import PagerView from "react-native-pager-view";
This was causing error, Expo PagerView at this time is not supported on web and cause complete web build to stop even without mentioning the cause.
Just remove it and it will build again web builds.
If you want to use it then
const [PagerView, setPagerView] = useState(null);

// Loading this way because PagerView is not available on the web
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadPagerView = async () => {
      if (!isPlatformWeb) {
        console.log("I am not on web");
        const PagerViewModule = await import("react-native-pager-view");
        setPagerView(() => PagerViewModule.default);
      } else {
        console.log("I am on web");
      }
    };

    loadPagerView();
  }, []);

then Use it.
